# copy first 100 files from directory which have a specific sentence inside the file

Tags: unix, cp

Copy first 100 files from one directory /ctm/logs to another /data/input

These files must have the sentence "completed with error code zero" inside them

Is there any method?

Answer (score 0):

`cd` into your `/ctm/logs` directory, then use this:

```sh
grep -lr "completed with error code zero" . | head -100 | xargs -I% cp "%" /data/input
```

Double check to make sure the desired 100 files are being copied. If there is an issue with the ordering this is better suited to be solved with a small program/script rather than a one-liner.